# Nativescript Angular 2 Telerik Ui Not Loading

Tags: angular, telerik, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-telerik-ui

Well, I do everything like the instalation guide  http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/nativescript-ui/getting-started

```
import { SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES } from "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular";
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NativeScriptModule,
        NativeScriptHttpModule,
        NativeScriptFormsModule,
        CalendarModule,
        AppRoutingModule
        ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        SIDEDRAWER_DIRECTIVES,
        ],
...
```

I installed it via NPM but i still receive 
Failed to find module "nativescript-telerik-ui/sidedrawer/angular", relative to app/tns_modules/

Answer (score 1):

They have changed the package. Now, you have to install the plugin using below command:

```
tns plugin add nativescript-ui-sidedrawer
```